# read file from usb removable storage

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

in my application I want to read a file from usb removable storage
I have a.txt and i want to read it

```
void read() {
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
    String Model = device.getDeviceName();

    try {
        File file = new File(Model + "/a.txt");
        if (file.exists())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Model + "/a.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            textView.append(sCurrentLine + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

when check file exists return false and when opening and reading file throw exception

`java.io.filenotfoundexception :/dev/bus/001/002/a.txt: opent failed : EACCES (permission denied)`

in Manifest have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What is that Model

Comment: Check out your path try to log it. to compare with exists your path should be exactly the same

Comment: `/dev/bus/001/002/a.txt`. That is an impossible non existend file system path. Which File:exists() already told you. You should return then and stop with your code. Now you continue as if nothing has happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

none of this solution worked for me
I searched and found this library

[Open source library to access USB Mass Storage devices on Android without rooting your device](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums)

tested and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on or above lollipop you need to ask permissions in java code.
check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/7457753

Comment: do that but still throw exception

Comment: what is the exception

Comment: java.io.filenotfoundexception :/dev/bus/001/002/a.txt: opent failed : EACCES (permission denied)

Comment: final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                          .getAbsolutePath(), filename);  try this to get path

Comment: Check this Example:  http://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/bus/001/002/a.txt.
```

That is an impossible non existend file system path. Which File:exists() already told you. You should return then and stop with your code. Now you continue as if nothing has happened.

You better had asked or googled 'how to determine path to usb pen drive'.

Well have a look at second or third item returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

You are sure your device supports OTG?

Comment: I try getExternalFilesDirs() and not work, my device support OTG

Comment: Please tell us the paths you get from getExternalFilesDirs() for both devices. Tell if you use a micro SD card in them. It would be nice if you showed the used code.